# Looping through a list of arrays to count the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, if-statement

I am been having trouble counting the number of objects in this array in  javascript.
Below is the array of objects i try to count with my code.

```
       <script>

var arr = [
    {"gateways":["ccu1"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v3"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_cam"]},
    {"gateways":["v2","v3","v4","ccu2"],"manufacturer":["homematic","intertechno"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v2","ccu1","ccu2"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["gw_none"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_cam"]},
    {"gateways":["v3","ccu2"],"manufacturer":["homematic","fs20","intertechno","elro","Eltako Enocean"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v3","v4"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v3","v4"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v2"],"manufacturer":["intertechno"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_other"]}
];
var counter = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    //console.log(arr[i]);

    for(var index in arr[i]) {
        console.log(index);

        if(counter[index] === undefined) {
            counter[index] = [];
        }

    }
}
console.log(counter);
    </script>
```

I want the number of the objects to push into the empty array "counter" when you console log "counter" e.g.

gateways
        ccu2  42
          v4    70
          v2    95
          v3    91
        v4plus  32
        ccu1    16
       gw_none  10

ip
       ip_cam   4
       ip_other 10
       ip_none  4

ir
       ir_yes   13
       ir_no    18

manufacturer
       homematic    24
       fs20     59
       intertechno  38
       elro    63
       homeeasy  40
       somfy     11

I am new to programming and trying my hands on some few exercises like this one but i got stuck. I'm left with the codes to put the object counter to the empty array. I have tried but cannot let it work. I would appreciate any help and i hope my assignment makes sense and is understandable.

Comment: aren't there `arr.length` objects in the array?

Comment: Start with initializing `counter` as an object, not an array, i.e. `var counter = {};`. Arrays use numeric keys while you want to use strings as keys. http://jsfiddle.net/frsbawwz/

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 if(counter[index] === undefined) {
        counter[index] = [];
 }
```

To this:

```
 if(counter[index] === undefined) {
        counter[index] = [];
 }
 counter[index].push( arr[i][index] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code is helpful.

```js
var arr = [
    {"gateways":["ccu1"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v3"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_cam"]},
    {"gateways":["v2","v3","v4","ccu2"],"manufacturer":["homematic","intertechno"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v2","ccu1","ccu2"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["gw_none"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_cam"]},
    {"gateways":["v3","ccu2"],"manufacturer":["homematic","fs20","intertechno","elro","Eltako Enocean"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_cam","ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v3","v4"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v3","v4"],"manufacturer":["homematic"],"ir":["ir_no"],"ip":["ip_other"]},
    {"gateways":["v2"],"manufacturer":["intertechno"],"ir":["ir_yes"],"ip":["ip_other"]}
];


var types = Object.keys(arr[0]); //Returns ["gateways","manufacturer","ir","ip"]
var counter = {};
types.forEach(function(type){
  var values = [].concat.apply([], arr.map(function(d){ return d[type] })); // Find all values for each key like gateways
  //Count occurrence of each value
  var counts = {};  
  for(var i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
    var num = values[i];
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1;
  }
  counter[type] = counts;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(counter));
```

**Output Obtained:**

```
{
    "gateways": {
        "ccu1": 2,
        "v3": 5,
        "v2": 3,
        "v4": 3,
        "ccu2": 3,
        "gw_none": 1
    },
    "manufacturer": {
        "homematic": 8,
        "intertechno": 3,
        "fs20": 1,
        "elro": 1,
        "Eltako Enocean": 1
    },
    "ir": {
        "ir_no": 5,
        "ir_yes": 4
    },
    "ip": {
        "ip_cam": 6,
        "ip_other": 7
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but i sat down and thought i got what i was missing;

```
        //first we initialised counter 
    var counter = [];

    //we then loop over the big array
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

        //we save then the single objects
        var obj = arr[i];

        // We then evaluate Object -> looping and count on each entry
        for(var key in obj) {

        //check whether there is already an entry for the respective
        //index (gateways, Manufacturer etc)
            if(counter[key] === undefined) {
                counter[key] = [];
            }


            //Save the individual array of Object entries
            var arr2 = obj[key];

            //Looping and counting the array
            for(var k=0; k<arr2.length; k++) {                    
                var entry = arr2[k];

                //Check whether there is already a counter for that
                //item
                if(counter[key][entry] === undefined) {
                    counter[key][entry] = 1;
                } else {
                    counter[key][entry]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(counter);
```